# C# Lambda with Console.Read

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, console-application

I was asking this to myself for quite few days and it is time as I need a help on this..

I have sample code that looks like

```
int nTestCase  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   
string[] inputStrings = new string[nTestCase];             

for (int i =0; i<nTestCase;i++)
 {
   inputStrings[i] = Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Is there any possibility to avoid extensive for loop over here. Just a thought of replacing it with Lambda expresssions?

this question might sound crazy, but I just want to know whether Lambda can handle Console.Read for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int nTestCase  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] inputStrings = Enumerable.Range(0, nTestCase)
                                  .Select(x => Console.ReadLine())
                                  .ToArray();
```

or even

```
string[] inputStrings = Enumerable.Range(0, Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()))
                                  .Select(x => Console.ReadLine())
                                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: It also worth mentioning that OP's terminology is completely broken

Comment: Excellent. Just a piece of code that I was looking for :) Thanks!

Comment: @zerkms: Could you explain *how* the question OP's terminology is "completely broken"?

Comment: @stakx: yep, OP confuses LINQ extension methods and lambda-functions.

Comment: @zerkms: I agree that there is a difference. But the terminology isn't *so* terribly wrong, considering that LINQ operators (extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>`) usually require lambdas (actually, delegates) as their arguments.

Comment: @stakx: "usually require lambdas (**actually, delegates**)" -- exactly. To substitute an explicit loop with an `IEnumerable` you need to use LINQ extension methods. You additionally need to have some delegates which do not have to be anonymous functions. So, the key here is LINQ, not lambda functions.